# How to prevent entity framework 5 from setting foreign key property to null when deleting the referenced object in optional one-to-many references

Tags: entity-framework

Entity Framework (version 5) set the foreign key property to null when delete the referenced object.
For example:

```
public class Category 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Category ParentCategory {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Category> ChildCategories {get;set;}
}
```

Due to the document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738695.aspx , 
EF will set ParentCategory to null for all children when deleting the parent Category.

My question is how to prevent this default behavior by throw an exception while deleting the parent instead of leaving child categories as orphans?

One possible way is to hook into DbContext.SaveChanges(), check if ChildCategories.Any() and throw an exception, but it looks ugly :-(